# How do I know a beaten egg has “set” while cooking stovetop rice pudding?

Tags: eggs, rice, pudding

The pudding is good, nice and creamy. My concern is feeding people uncooked egg as the time to stir in egg mixture is more a texture while stirring than a time to be sure the egg is cooked into the pudding.

Comment: Is it a pasteurized egg? If so, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Wow! I just googled that. I didn't know that even existed as a thing…. then again, the US does odd things to its eggs anyway, so it's less surprising.

Comment: @Tetsujin the most criminal thing about US eggs is that our chickens are fed "feed" and chicken skin and chicken eggs are a sickly color, rather than the deep yellow of grain fed. Pasteurized eggs are surprisingly not that different from normal eggs. But they do cost more.

Answer (score 3):

How hot is the pudding?
At or near boiling the egg will be set by the time you can stir it in, certainly by the time you can serve it.

One egg in a couple of pints of piping hot (semi) liquid will be at temperature almost immediately.